# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I want to create tabs on pure js and decided to implement it through "data-attr".

```
var allTabs = document.querySelectorAll('.tab'); //all tabs on page

var clickTabHandler = function (event) {

    var target = event.target;

    var id = target.getAttribute('data-content');

    alert(id);

};

for (var i = 0; i < allTabs.length; i++) {
    allTabs[i].onclick = clickTabHandler(event);
}
```

in the console get : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined;

Why?

Comment: where is that loop called? you are immediately invoking `clickTabHandler`

Answer (score 3):

replace this line

```
allTabs[i].onclick = clickTabHandler(event);
```

by

```
allTabs[i].onclick = clickTabHandler;
```

since `this` and `event` will be passed to it implicity

Comment: Thanks for this, I've been fighting with an undefined issue for an hour.